# Creating an updatable League table

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to create some additions for our gaming club's blog including a scoreboard for our Warmachine league and an update form for players to submit their games. I want the update form to submit various game results and an optional battle report to a mysql database, storing the information on a per game basis.

I've already set up the form and I've managed to get it to submit the information via php, but I'm not sure how to get it to add all the scoring fields into a total and return the information into a table organised by rank, sorry if this sounds really simple but I'm completely new to this and I just can't seem to figure out how.

Here's my php:

```
<?php
define('DB_NAME', '');
define('DB_USER', '');
define('DB_PASSWORD', '');
define('DB_HOST', '');


$link = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);

// Check connection

if (!$link) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
$db_selected = mysql_select_db(DB_NAME, $link);

if (!$db_selected) {
    die('Can\'t use ' . DB_NAME . ': ' . mysql_error());
}

$value = $_POST[player];
$value2 = $_POST[opponent];
$value31 = $_POST[day];
$value32 = $_POST[month];
$value33 = $_POST[year];
$value4 = $_POST[ofaction];
$value5 = $_POST[pfaction];
$value6 = $_POST[painted];
$value7 = $_POST[won];
$value8 = $_POST[casterkill];
$value9 = $_POST[controlpoints];
$value10 = $_POST[report];

$sql = "INSERT INTO LeagueGames (Player, Opponent, Date, OFaction, PFaction, Painted, Won, CasterKill, ControlPoints, Report) VALUES ('$value', '$value2', '$value33''-''$value32''-''$value31', '$value4', '$value5', '$value6', '$value7', '$value8', '$value9', '$value10')";

if (!mysql_query($sql)) {
    die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
}

mysql_close();

echo "Game Added"


?>
```

Comment: You're vulnerable and will be hacked eventually.

Comment: What are you actually asking here?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I totally understand your question, but I think you could use the MySQL SUM function. This would provide a total for you, without having to store the total in your database.

To calculate and display this figure, use a query like:

```
SELECT SUM(Won, CasterKill, ControlPoints) FROM LeagueGames;
```

Comment: How would I use that with the php file?

Comment: I think this link should help you with PHP + MySQL: [PHP MySQL APIs](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php)

You would do something LIKE:
    $sql = "SELECT SUM(field, field, field) AS total FROM table;
    $result = $mysqli->query($sql);
    $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
    echo htmlentities($row['total']);

Comment: That helps, but each row in the table represents a game that was played and it's results, so each player will be listed in multiple game entries. How do I get it to select all the rows with that players name and add those scores. Sorry if my explanation wasn't thorough enough...